# Powershell does not display remoted executed outputs of .NET commands in Local Powershell session

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I would like to pass an Error generated from a Remote PowerShell Session  back to the Local Session:
(This Works)

```
Invoke-Command -Session $DevSession -ScriptBlock {sqlps -command E:\admin\DBA\Refresh_SQL_Config_Scripts.ps1 $args[0] $args[1]; $error} -args $SQLServer, $dbName -ErrorVariable +scriptDEVerror
```

Problem: I would like to get it in a friendly readable format using the slightly ajusted code. I get my standard results but the $error shows as blank.
Code here:

```
Invoke-Command -Session $DevSession -ScriptBlock {sqlps -command E:\admin\DBA\Refresh_SQL_Config_Scripts.ps1 $args[0] $args[1]; $error.tostring() } -args $SQLServer, $dbName -ErrorVariable +scriptDEVerror
```

Or even better would be:

```
Invoke-Command -Session $DevSession -ScriptBlock {sqlps -command E:\admin\DBA\Refresh_SQL_Config_Scripts.ps1 $args[0] $args[1]; $error[0].tostring() } -args $SQLServer, $dbName -ErrorVariable +scriptDEVerror
```

Does anyone know of a way to get this working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't getting anything back from `$Error[0].tostring()` inside the script block because `Invoke-Command` is redirecting the remote session's error stream to the error stream in your local session.  You need to look for your error text there:

```
Invoke-Command -Session $DevSession -ScriptBlock {sqlps -command E:\admin\DBA\Refresh_SQL_Config_Scripts.ps1 $args[0] $args[1] } -args $SQLServer, $dbName -ErrorVariable +scriptDEVerror
$Error[0].tostring()
```

Edit: Per the comments:

```
$Error.clear()

Invoke-Command -Session $DevSession -ScriptBlock {sqlps -command E:\admin\DBA\Refresh_SQL_Config_Scripts.ps1 $args[0] $args[1] } -args $SQLServer, $dbName -ErrorVariable +scriptDEVerror

$devErrors = [array]$error
[array]::reverse($devErrors)
```

Should give you a reversed array of the errors from the invocation in $devErrors.

Comment: You are correct thank you, It helped me  realized that the Error text was actually redirected to the local session but in a reverse order of  the text. So the output I was looking for turned out to be $Error[10].ToString() + $Error[9].ToString() instead of $error[0].ToString()

Comment: I guess now I will have the fun of reaearching how to parse error message  strings that could end up anywhere within an array :(

Comment: Left a suggestion in answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add additional information to `scriptDEVerror`, you need to make sure that information is an Error if you expect them to get included in your ErrorVariable.  `$error.ToString()` and `$error[0].ToString()` are not errors, those are strings. Try writing what you want to the error stream using `Write-Error`, e.g.

```
Invoke-Command -Session $DevSession -ScriptBlock {sqlps -command E:\admin\DBA\Refresh_SQL_Config_Scripts.ps1 $args[0] $args[1]; Write-Error $error[0].tostring() } -args $SQLServer, $dbName -ErrorVariable +scriptDEVerror
```

Comment: I appreciate the response and another avenue of troubleshooting I can explore.
The Write-error fails with an exception:
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException